Understanding the "%DURATION%" field in Envoy access logs
This is an example of logs for an inbound request from my Envoy Proxy instance (which is in fact the Edge Proxy, aka ingress pod, in my OpenShift installation with Istio enabled):
[2024-12-13T09:38:04.576Z] "POST /SomeGrpcApi/MyApi HTTP/2" 200 - via_upstream - "-" 279 147 1073 226 "21.37.16.1,21.37.12.122,21.37.1.33" "grpc-java-netty/1.41.0" "855230dc-8934-4g46-afa8-73a608b7f5fa" "some-host.example.com" "29.64.6.238:8080" outbound|8081||example.example-svc.svc.cluster.local 21.37.23.240:59452 21.37.23.240:10802 21.37.1.33:3478 some-host.example.com -

According to the documentation numbers 1073 226 are %DURATION%
and %RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% respectively. But the documentation doesn't say much about what these figures really mean, e.g.:
%DURATION%
  HTTP/THRIFT
    Total duration in milliseconds of the request from the start time to the last byte out.
  TCP
    Total duration in milliseconds of the downstream connection.
  UDP
    Not implemented (0).


Which of these definitions is valid for my GRPC connection?
What is the 'start time' for the request? Is it the time point when a
client starts sending the first byte to the server, or when this first byte reaches the server, or when the first portion of data was received and processed by the server (e.g. TCP or TLS handshake happened), or what?
Does the "last byte" mean the time point of the upstream request sending end, or the upstream response receiving end, or the response sending to the client end?

I noticed that %RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% is always less than or equals to %DURATION% so I conclude that %DURATION% = %RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% + t. So in other words, what is t? Does it include network delays between client and server?
